# How to maintain formatting for numbers in multi-value combo box?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that holds data of type Number that has a format of "R-"00 and in my Form that is linked to this table, I have a multi-combo box. When I go to select the values, they are correct - they all have the "R-00n" formatting where n is the actual number entry (auto-numbered). However, when I make my selection, the value will just read as 1, 2, 3 instead of R-001, R-002, R-003. How do I maintain my formatting after selections?

My query is `SELECT Reference_ID FROM References` for the Data of the combo-box in the form and it is pulling the right records, formatted correctly ("R-001, R-002, R-003") but when I make my selections, the value in the form is only 1, 2, 3. It drops the formatting. Is there something I need to configure in my Form to maintain the custom formatting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean `ListBox` and not `Combobox`, right?

So I also suppose you already have some code to read the selected items of your ListBox like this:

```
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In YourListBox.ItemsSelected
    Debug.Print YourListBox.ItemData(item)
Next
```

Regarding your problem:

You wrote that the tables field `Reference_ID` stores the number itself, but because it is formatted by `"R-"000` it displays values like `R-003`.

So you already know, that the value itself stored is without formatting.
You could check that by retrieving the data like this:

```
?DLookup("Reference_ID","References","Reference_ID = 3")
```

It will show up `3` and not `R-003`.

So the same belongs when you read the data from the ListBoxes selected items.

As far as I know you can't read out the formatted text from the ListBox. But what you can do is to format the read value yourself:

```
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In YourListBox.ItemsSelected
    Debug.Print Format(YourListBox.ItemData(item), "R-000")
Next
```

Another approach could be to set the Row Source of your ListBox to already formatted values:

```
Select Format(Reference_ID, "R-000") From References
```

Comment: When I try and edit the value of the ListBox in the for loop, I get an error, 7878, that the data is unable to be changed.

Comment: Is this a new question? What about the topic I answered? Does this work well?

Comment: In your original question is not one word regaring editing any value. It was about reading and formatting. Maybe you finally show us your code making trouble,

Comment: I have tried the For Each loop where I set the value to my custom format but it is giving me a run-time error of 2222

Comment: Why do you want to apply the format to the Listbox? It's already displayed properly as I understood. Only when retrieving the underlying value from the Listbox, then is no more formatted you said. Once again: Show us your code please.